# Customizing Alert Dialog Box -- Ok Button is unresponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating some custom Alert Dialog boxes and while the box styles properly the Ok button that I insert is unresponsive. Below is the code to reference.

```
function CustomAlert(){
    this.render = function(dialog){
      ...
      ...
      document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = "<button onclick = 'Alert.ok()'>OK</button>";
    }

    this.ok = function(){
      document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  var Alert = new CustomAlert();

  $('#button1').click(function(){
    Alert.render("Heyooo!!!");
  })
```

The Alert.render function fires correctly. When I try to trigger the Alert.ok function (inserted with the innerHTML function) I get " Uncaught ReferenceError: Alert is not defined" referencing line 1 of my index.html file, which is the DOCTYPE declaration.

Why is "Alert" not defined when called in this context?

Comment: Probably is because Alert is not on scope...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague.  Keep in mind that the JavaScript `alert()` method cannot be styled, so you would need to create your own modal.  I use one like this (very responsive):

```js
function styledAlert(message){
  
  document.getElementById('alertText').innerHTML = message;
  document.getElementById('alertWrapper').style.display = 'block';
  
  
  }
```

```css
#alertWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  }

#alertBox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  border-radius: 25px;
  }

#alertAccept {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  }

#alertText {
  margin: 15px;
  color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div id="alertWrapper"><div id="alertBox"><p id="alertText"></p><button id="alertAccept" onclick="document.getElementById('alertWrapper').style.display = 'none'">OK</button></div></div>

Type in an alert message: <input type="text" onblur="styledAlert(this.value)"/> And then blur the textbox to see the alert . . .
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please make your question a little more specific on the end result that you are seeking.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize my question was vague. I figured out that it's a problem with variable scope I guess? If I write the script in plain JS and remove  $(document).ready it works fine. If I try to wrap the plain JS in an IIFE I get another Uncaught reference error.